# compiling HPL-2.0_FERMIv15

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, cluster, cuda

when i compile xhpl i always get the error message:
./xhpl: error while loading shared libraries: libdgemm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

when i type ldd xhpl:

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007f885e5000)

```
    libdgemm.so.1 => not found
    libcudart.so.10.2 => /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.2 (0x0000007f884db000)
    libcublas.so.10 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.10 (0x0000007f837fd000)
    libmpi.so.12 => /opt/mpich/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x0000007f834f5000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x0000007f834b8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007f8348c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007f83333000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007f885ba000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007f8319f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000007f8318a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000007f83173000)
    libcublasLt.so.10 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcublasLt.so.10 (0x0000007f811ad000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007f810f3000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x0000007f80f53000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007f80f2f000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x0000007f80d5b000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000007f80d2e000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x0000007f80cfe000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x0000007f7f345000)
```

How can i set the link to libdgemm.so.1? i found it in /home/mpiuser/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v15/src/cuda/libdgemm.so.1

Thanks for ur help guys!

Answer (score 0):

`ld`, the dynamic linker, searches for files in a number of system folders and also in those contained in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

So, please try the commands

```
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/mpiuser/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v15/src/cuda
# ldd xhpl
```

(The syntax for setting environment variables differs in different shells so please report any error.)

If you are using `bash` as your login shell, you can add the first line, i.e.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/mpiuser/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v15/src/cuda
```

to your file `~/.bashrc` (ideally at the end) so that from the next time you open a terminal/shell, the variable will be set correctly and automatically.